How to make node.js ignore css files
I can't run the tests with Mocha in my vanilla javascript project when I have a CSS file import because I can't get Node to ignore that specific extension.
I get this error:
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".css"
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:124:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:84:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:603:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34)
    at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:21)

Here is a sample repository to replicate the issue, hoping it will be helpful:
https://github.com/Marco0491/mocha-issue-simulation
Everything I've found so far is outdated and doesn't work in my case.


Nodejs doesn't natively support CSS imports, you need to explicitly ignore the imports with configuration.
Mocha won't handle CSS imports, you need to use a preprocessor like Babel to transpile & then ignore the CSS imports.

npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/register ignore-styles --save-dev


create .babelrc file

{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}


update your test/setup.js file to ignore css

require('ignore-styles');
require('@babel/register')({
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
});


update your execution scripts package.json

"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --require ./test/setup.js"
}

